# Closing a Movieclip and Return to Scene One (and first frame label)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm incorporating Flash for the first in my site http://grdnbklyn.com/press.html .
This is a newbie question -- it should a simple navigation but it has had me stuck for a while. 
I would like users to click any button on the stage (listed or thumbnails) and open a MC, then close the MC, using a close button , then return to Scene One, which is frame labeled "home".

I am able to successfully open and close the Movieclip but I am not directed back Scene One. When the MC closes, the thumbnail buttons are inactive.

Here is some sample code from The last frame of the MC actions.

```
stop();

closeVogue_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickVogue);

function onClickVogue(event:MouseEvent):void
{ gotoAndStop("home"); 

}
```

Perhaps, there is a simpler way to achieve this. I'm not sure but I'd appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

"gotoAndStop("home");" in this case will send the MC to its "home" frame if one exists. Writing "stage.gotoAndStop("home");" will send the root timeline to its "home" frame if one exists, that might be the solution. Ask any questions you have about this.